# I have a large collection of small files of the same nature. Can I build dictionary on them all but compress each file individually?

Tags: python, algorithm, compression, machine-learning, storage

The corpus consists of strings (files names) and their checksums, so I expect its entropy to be higher than of normal text. Also the collection is too large to be analysed so I'm going to sample it to create global dictionary. Is there a fancy machine learning approach for my task?

Which algorithm or, better, library should I use?

I'm using python in case it matters.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=python+Entropy&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=off&tbs=&as_filetype=&as_rights=) is your friend.

Comment: @IvanKoblik: I wasn't trying to be funny or belittle the question. The non-generic link I provided was to quickly give the OP something to pursue since there didn't seem to many answers being given. I noticed several relevant-looking links in the search results.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use [sparse coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_coding). It allows you to use your data set to infer an overcomplete dictionary which is then used to encode your data. If your data is indeed of similar nature, this could work well for you.